# Can i run the ionic v1 project when i have ionic CLI 3.0.0

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Now i have the latest version of ionic 3.0.0. My `ionic version`: `3.0.0`.

And my `ionic info`:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.0.0
    Ionic CLI        : 3.0.0

System:

    Node       : v7.3.0
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002 
    ios-deploy : 1.9.0 
    ios-sim    : 5.0.13
```

Now i have two question in this. I searched , but not able to get the clear. If any one can answer. It will be helpful for many new bie like me.

So,

1.Now i have ionic 3.0.0. Then if i want to open the project in ionic v2. i will give ` ionic start newapp blank --v2 or (--ts_)'. And i will use some updated plugin having in ionic 3.0.0. Does it will work out. or i need to create a seperate project for ionic version 3 ??

2. Now i have old ionic 1 project that i am still working on. So once i update my ionic to`3.0.0`. Now what i done is :

`ionic start newapp blank --v1` then i copied my old project `www` folder to this `newapp` and i replaced it.

My question is. Still can i use angular js1 to code for this project also. And while make `ionic release` means when i want to put it in my app store. Does any problem will occur. Because i have create this project as `--v1`.

If yes when i create a new project `ionic start newapp blank --v1` its asking me `Link this app to your Ionic Dashboard to use tools like Ionic View? y/N` : what should i need to do

Please clarify me..thanks in advance

Comment: You mix up ionic-angular (the ionic version of your app) and ionic-cli. It's not clear which one you mean because they can both be v1 or v3

Comment: ionic start newapp blank --v1 worked fine for me and I have cli 3.x

Answer (score 7):

Using the ionic-cli version 3.0 you should be able to work on all versions of ionic projects.

The new cli will create an ionic v3 app by default. If you want to create an ionic v1 app, you need to add `--v1`. But if you are starting with a new app, I strongly recommend going for v2+.

Depending on the version your ionic app has, you need to add some additional plugins:

`@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular` – Ionic Angular project plugin that provides useful build tools and generators. (ionic v2+)
`@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1` – Ionic 1 project plugin that has functionality ported from the old CLI.
`@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova` – Essential for an Ionic/Cordova app.
`@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy` – For proxying CLI requests through a firewall.

I can't tell you if you need to link your app to the dashboard. If you are using the Ionic services (Push, View, etc), then it makes sense.

That being said, I have experienced quite a few "bugs" or inconsistent behaviour with the new cli, so you might need to downgrade if something doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same worry when I updated my Ionic to v3 (CLI 3.1.2).  They seem to really be pushing to use their cloud services (obviously, they want to start making some money on it).

When I tried the old v1 command:

```
ionic build ios
```

I received:

```
The build command has been renamed. To find out more, run:

  ionic cordova build --help
```

So, then I tried

```
ionic covdova build ios
```

That failed with this:

```
ionic package build ios
[ERROR] Your project file (./ionic.config.json) does not contain 'app_id'. Run ionic link.
```

So, after looking around a bit, I used this command and it worked:

```
ionic cordova build ios --v1
```

It asked me to install a couple of things, then chugged out a new successful build.  All good.

Comment: Just to add some info, to start a new v1 project just type:
[code]ionic start newapp blank --type=ionic1[/code]

Answer (score 1):

Please use following command as I had trouble with "--v1"

```
ionic start newapp blank --type=ionic1
```

As mentioned by @Samuel.

Answer (score 0):

Add Ionic 1 CLI to the **devDependency** list. Open **package.json** file in the project directory and add the following line to **devDependencies**.

> "@ionic/cli-framework": "^1.0.0-rc.2"

Example package.json:

[image: Screenshot of Example]

Answer (score 0):

Running `ionic repair` removed package.json and node_modules then, if prompted, run `npm audit fix`, and then you will be asked to `Install @angular/cli?`