# Getting started with IONIC Development

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Hi I am Angular developer and want to start developing ionic App. 
I found some links here [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43908809/9172846) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56339418/9172846)

So could anyone suggest that how to start with Ionic learning(step by step) with development with best practices as well. I am familiar with Angular(5) and node(v10.0.0).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have knowledge on Angular 2+, then you can easily learn ionic. It is almost same as Angular.

To get started with IONIC Framework, You can simply visit the [Official Site](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started).

Just install nodeJS and run `npm install -g ionic` to install the ionic dependencies globally and create a IONIC project by using `ionic start ProjectName Option`

Option can be blank, tabs and some others.

Comment: you can use any version of node or ionic. But it is best practice to always use latest version of it.  And latest version of ionic is v3