# How much time it will take to learn ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

I already know html,css, javascript  how much time it will take to learn ionic framework and how it is different from angularjs?

Answer (score 2):

Question could probably be considered off-topic, but I'll post answer since I had a similar question when I got started, as I didn't really understand what benefit Ionic was providing.

First off, Angular is a front-end Javascript framework used for making Web Apps.

The ionic framework provides a set of Web Components that will work across platforms, so you can code once as web project and port your project to different platforms (iOS, Android, even desktop :-o).

So, Ionic doesn't replace Angular, but rather can use Angular.  Actually in Ionic V4, the Ionic CLI just uses the Angluar CLI under the hood.

In my case, my goal was to use Angular to build web app, then wrap with Cordova to make an iOS mobile app out of it.  I decided not to use Ionic initially because I didn't understand what it was really doing and it seemed like "one more thing to learn" at a time when I was already learning Angular.

However, I ended up switching over to Ionic because I was running into weird UI problems when the iOS keyboard was displayed / not displayed (worked fine in web, but native iOS was wacky).  Seems like a silly reason, but the ionic components handled this scenario flawlessly.

Other benefits that I gained pretty much "for free" after switching over to ionic were:

- app menu with animation
- navigation transitions
- slide to reveal options for lists

I found learning to use the Ionic components was pretty straight forward and their documentation is pretty solid.

It's pretty easy to follow the [Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/cli) and spin up a new project to play with.

While I can't say how long it will take for you to learn, I hope this info helps... :-)